# How can I implement triggers in cockroachDB

Tags: triggers, cockroachdb

I'm trying to migrate a database written in PostgreSQL to cockroachDB
I want to know if there's a way to implement the trigger in SQL in cockroachDB. I couldn't find a statement that would do the same in their documentation

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish with triggers? There are many kinds of workarounds, yet CockroachDB doesn't support triggers directly.

Answer (score 2):

CockroachDB doesn't support triggers as of 2021.

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/sql-feature-support.html